# unable to insert data to SQL using SQLi connection method

Tags: html, mysql

Am using SQLi connection method to connect to SQL database in localhost and the following is my code to insert data to SQL DB

### SQL table

```
create table `test`(
`id` int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`first` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`last` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

### form processing

```
<?php
$db_username="sanoj";
$db_password="123456";
try {
#connection 
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=localtest', $db_username, $db_password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$data = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO test VALUES(:first)');
$data->bindParam(':first', $first);

$first = 'Huzoor Bux';
$data->execute();

#exception handiling
} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

### form

```
<FORM method="post" action="for.php">
        <input type="text" name="first" placeholder="first"><br>
        <input type="text" name="last" placeholder="last">
        <input type="submit">
</FORM>
```

### ERROR

```
SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this method it will work

```
// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


$first=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'first');
$last=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'last');

$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(first, last)VALUES('$first', '$last')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
echo "$first <br>";
echo "$last";

mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#connection 
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=localtest', $db_username, $db_password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$data = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO test (first, last) VALUES (:first, :last)');
$first = 'Huzoor Bux';
$last = 'Bux Huz';
$data->execute(array(':first' => $first, ':last' => $last));

#exception handiling
```

Notice that you are using PDO which is correct. [Using mysql_connect() is deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php).

Comment: how do you get input from user when its like this $first = 'Huzoor Bux';
$last = 'Bux Huz';

Comment: $first = $_POST['first']; $last = $_POST['last'];

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are adding rows with one field to a table with two (or more) columns.
You may need to change your SQL like "INSERT INTO test (firstFieldName) VALUES (:first)".

Comment: how to add second field "last"

Comment: INSERT INTO test (firstFieldName, lastFieldName) VALUES (:first, :last)

Comment: still i get the same error   SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: Could you show us the table structure? Something like the CREATE sentence that shows how many and what kind of columns do you have in test...

Comment: i tried this method INSERT INTO test (firstFieldName, lastFieldName) VALUES (:first, :last)   and get this ERROR                                       SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Comment: Of course you have to change firstFieldName for the real name of the first column, and same for lastFieldName. Please show us the table structure.

Comment: added SQL structure in QUestion

Comment: Oh, I see. Try, after binding with bindParam to first and last, the following query: INSERT INTO test (first, last) VALUES (:first, :last)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63269/discussion-between-sanoj-and-liopic).

Comment: still i get negative result

Comment: I noticed you declared $first = 'Huzoor Bux' AFTER the bindParam() call. It should be declared BEFORE. Or alternatively, delete all bindParam() calls, and pass to execute() the parameters. I mean something like: $data->execute(array(':first' => 'Hello', ':last' => 'Bye')));

Answer (score 0):

https://www.drupal.org/node/1279532

Take a look of this link, It will help you to sort out your prob.

Comment: can i take whole look up your exception.

Comment: Is there any rule_hash feild in your table if yes than drop it run once again